# Insertion and selection at same table at same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance

Since I am new to Sql server, Could any one please clarify on this ?

Consider the case,

I have a table **"dbo.test"** which contains 100 million records.

10 select statement is running on the table **"dbo.test"**, each selection will return 1 million records.

Now I want to insert 1 million records to the same table **"dbo.test"**. but I am not going to select the new data,(which I am inserting, I have filters accordingly).

Here can I insert the 1 million, or need to wait for all select statements to complete.

How about performance, if I start insertion ?

Queries are welcome.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag.

Comment: Yes @Gordon, but i have added tags for performance.

Comment: Let me clarify...  so it sounds like what you're saying is that the new rows have no chance of being picked up by the Select queries
(they don't fit the Where or Join, etc) ...  Is that right?  ... So there's no issue of "hiding" the new rows.  We're just concerned with performance and when to do the insert.

Answer (score 5):

For this you need to understand the locking behavior in sql server. Sql Server obtain locks on the resources when it is accessing resources(rows) in database for any operation.

What type of lock will be obtained depends on the type of operation you are doing and the transaction isolation level you have.

By default you have read committed transaction isolation level. and your reads(select queries) will obtain shared locks on the resources(rows), it means other users who are also reading rows can access them rows.

But if another user updates a row sql server will obtain an exclusive lock on the row and it will not be available for read until the update statement has been committed.

Inserting rows into a table with default read committed transaction isolation level shouldn't make any difference to the rows thats being read by another user unless sql server has to lock some rows to check for a condition while inserting new rows. again this depends how you are inserting row.

I would suggest you to do some reading on sql server transaction isolation levels and sql server lock behavior before you go ahead with your inserts :)

Especially look into repeatable read transaction isolation level which allows you to insert data, but than you can have some dirty read.

Comment: Thanks @M.Ali,  In all select statements I used, with (nolock) table hint.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using SQL Server, use [OUTPUT clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).
Why would you need to SELECT 1 million rows, well that's another story...

Comment: this is not uncommon in data warehouses.  I have "reports" going out to clients at my workplace every day with 10 million rows.  Big data is big :)